# How to extract name and version from string

Tags: c#, regex, parsing, comparison, version

I have many filenames such as:

```
libgcc1-5.2.0-r0.70413e92.rbt.xar
python3-sqlite3-3.4.3-r1.0.f25d9e76.rbt.xar
u-boot-signed-pad.bin-v2015.10+gitAUTOINC+1b6aee73e6-r0.02df1c57.rbt.xar
```

I need to reliably extract the name, version and "rbt" or "norbt" from this. What is the best way? I am trying regex, something like:

```
(?<fileName>.*?)-(?<version>.+).(rbt|norbt).xar
```

Issue is the file name and version both can have multiple semi colons. So I am not sure if there is an answer by I have two questions:

1. What is the best strategy to extract values such as these?
2. How would I be able to figure out which version is greater?

Expected output is:

```
libgcc1, 5.2.0-r0.70413e92, rbt
python3-sqlite3, 3.4.3-r1.0.f25d9e76, rbt
u-boot-signed-pad.bin, v2015.10+gitAUTOINC+1b6aee73e6-r0.02df1c57, rbt
```

Comment: In the version `.+` I think you also need a `?` to make it non-greedy

Comment: what is the expected output for the 3 examples?

Comment: The '10+gitAUTOINC+' in the third filename is an indication of too much variability in the 'version' part. To extract reliably the wanted information you need some guarantees about the format of the filenames. Are there any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you what you want without using Regex:

```
var fileNames = new List<string>(){
    "libgcc1-5.2.0-r0.70413e92.rbt.xar",
    "python3-sqlite3-3.4.3-r1.0.f25d9e76.rbt.xar",
    "u-boot-signed-pad.bin-v2015.10+gitAUTOINC+1b6aee73e6-r0.02df1c57.rbt.xar"
};
foreach(var file in fileNames){
    var spl = file.Split('-');
    string name = string.Join("-",spl.Take(spl.Length-2));
    string versionRbt = string.Join("-",spl.Skip(spl.Length-2));
    string rbtNorbt = versionRbt.IndexOf("norbt") > 0 ? "norbt" : "rbt";
    string version = versionRbt.Replace($".{rbtNorbt}.xar","");
    Console.WriteLine($"name={name};version={version};rbt={rbtNorbt}");
}
```

Output:

```
name=libgcc1;version=5.2.0-r0.70413e92;rbt=rbt
name=python3-sqlite3;version=3.4.3-r1.0.f25d9e76;rbt=rbt
name=u-boot-signed-pad.bin;version=v2015.10+gitAUTOINC+1b6aee73e6-r0.02df1c57;rbt=rbt
```

Edit:

Or using Regex:

```
var m = Regex.Match(file,@"^(?<fileName>.*)-(?<version>.+-.+)\.(rbt|norbt)\.xar$");
string name = m.Groups["fileName"].Value;
string version = m.Groups["version"].Value;
string rbtNorbt = m.Groups[1].Value;
```

The output will be the same. Both approaches assum that "version" has one `-`.

Answer (score 0):

Tested following code and work perfectly with Regex.  I used option Right-To-Left

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication107
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] inputs = {
                                  "libgcc1-5.2.0-r0.70413e92.rbt.xar",
                                  "python3-sqlite3-3.4.3-r1.0.f25d9e76.rbt.xar",
                                  "u-boot-signed-pad.bin-v2015.10+gitAUTOINC+1b6aee73e6-r0.02df1c57.rbt.xar"
                              };

            string pattern = @"(?'prefix'.+)-(?'middle'[^-][\w+\.]+-[\w+\.]+)\.(?'extension'[^\.]+).\.xar";

            foreach (string input in inputs)
            {
                Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern, RegexOptions.RightToLeft);
                Console.WriteLine("prefix : '{0}', middle : '{1}', extension : '{2}'",
                    match.Groups["prefix"].Value,
                    match.Groups["middle"].Value,
                    match.Groups["extension"].Value
                    );
            }
            Console.ReadLine();


        }
    }


}
```